# apach/spark container in docker do not run pyspark

Tags: docker, apache-spark, pip, delta-lake

I pull the version `3.5.0` of spark with `docker` from https://hub.docker.com/r/apache/spark with this command: `docker pull apache/spark:3.5.0`.

I want install `delta-lake=3.0.0` in this docker container and ryn `pysaprk` shell to code in that for delt-lake.

I use `docker run -it  apache/spark /bin/sh` and then install delta-spark with `pip install delta-spark==3.0.0`. But It  has two problem:

1. the following error is accured and it can not install `delta-spark`:

   WARNING: The directory '/home/spark/.cache/pip' or its parent directory is not owned or is not writable by the current user. The cache has been disabled. Check the permissions and owner of that directory. If executing pip with sudo, you may want sudo's -H flag.
2. it go to download the `pyspark=3.5.0` again

the first error can solve when use root user with `docker run -ti --user 0 --name spark apache/spark /bin/sh`, but the second problem accrued again.

When I want use pyspark shell it dos not possible to run with `docker run -it  apache/spark /bin/sh` or `docker run -ti --user 0 --name spark apache/spark /bin/sh` and must run it separately with `docker run -it apache/spark /opt/spark/bin/pyspark`.

how can solve this problem?

Comment: "*it go to download the `pyspark=3.5.0` again*? Why do you think it shouldn't? Does `pip list` lists pyspark 3.5.0?

Comment: "*When I want use pyspark shell it dos not possible to run with `docker run -it  apache/spark /bin/sh`*" What does it mean "not possible"? What if try to run `docker run -it  apache/spark /bin/sh` and then `/opt/spark/bin/pyspark` in the shell?

Comment: Did you finally solve the issue?

Comment: @phd b.c. it must has pyspark in SPARK_HOME variable and why must it downlands it agian?

Comment: @DanielPerezEfremova No unfortunately.

Comment: did you tested the entrypoint modification I proposed?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to run pyspark using docker run -it apache/spark /bin/sh, I suggest you to modify the Docker entry point temporarily with the following:

```
docker run -it --entrypoint /bin/sh apache/spark /opt/spark/bin/pyspark
```